# iPhone - webViewDidFinishLoad is not called

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have an IB that contant an UIWebView

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PostFunHorosViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>{

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *description;
@end
```

And at ViewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    description.delegate = self;
    [self.description loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<div align='justify'>%@<div>",[@"This is test string" stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"\n" withString:@"<br/>"]] baseURL:nil];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"webViewDidFinishLoad");
}
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSLog(@"webViewDidStartLoad");
}
```

And this is how I add IB to my screen:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{   
    PostFunHorosViewController *postVC = [[PostFunHorosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PostFunHorosViewController" bundle:nil];
    [scroller addSubview:postVC.view];                   
    [postVC release];                
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

My problem is it never call webViewDidFinishLoad and webViewDidStartLoad.
Moreover it also stuck in

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([IHOROSAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

with no exception.

Am I miss something. Please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: loadHTMLString won't fire UIWebViewDelegate event

Comment: @adali - the delegate will fire on loadHTMLString.

Comment: You're overriding [NSObject's `-description`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description) method. This asks for troubles and bugs. `NSLog(…)` anybody? Kinda troublesome nobody has remarked this so far. It's been a year now, already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -

```
self.description.delegate = self;  (in viewDidLoad)
```

earlier you are doing -

```
description.delegate = self;
```

while you haven't define instance variable, instead you have defined property.

Comment: Thank for response. It still stucks at @autoreleasepool

Comment: can you add the crash logs, or what is present in the console.

Comment: It's not stuck there.  When you pause execution, the debugger will stop there because that's where your run loop is getting run.

Comment: There're nothing in the console. It still stucks at autoreleasepool with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Comment: You also need to remove statement,  [postVC release];   Application is crashing due to this statement. Due to this event targeted a freed object.

Comment: One more suggestion, approach taken by you is not good, you have to use navigation controller for pushing up new view controllers, instead of just adding subview. There are couple of tutorials present for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Instead taking the delegate programatically try to taking the outlet as you have XIB file.
One morething I would suggest to print like this,

```
description.delegate=self;
NSLog(@"Self %@",self);
```

So, you would have clear idea where you are setting the delegates.